# Java: More spans containing different styles cannot be converted with OpenHtmlToPdf into PDF format

Tags: java, openhtmltopdf

I am discovering OpenHtmlToPdf for converting html into pdf. Well it is working with my custom fonts, but when I give multiple span tags for styling it fails. In this case it is not loading the proper fonts....

```
<p>invalid format</p>
 
 <span style="font-family:'Courier Prime'">
      <span style="color:yellow">
             <span style="font-size:36pt">
                 Hello World!
            </span>
     </span> </span>
 
 <p>working format</p>
 
 <span style="font-family:'Courier
 Prime';color:yellow;font-size:36pt">Hello World!</span>
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZPXWD.jpg)

Code: This is the relevant part of the spring-boot service ...

```
@Service
public class HtmltoPdfServiceImpl implements HtmlToPdfService {
    @Autowired
    private PdfRendererBuilder pdfRendererBuilder;
    
    @Override
    public byte[] topdf(HtmlToPdfModel htmlmap) throws HtmlToPdfException {
        byte[] pdf;
        String html = htmlmap.getHtmlbody();
        try (ByteArrayOutputStream os = new ByteArrayOutputStream()){
            pdfRendererBuilder.withHtmlContent(html, "");
            pdfRendererBuilder.toStream(os);
            pdfRendererBuilder.run();
            pdf = os.toByteArray();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new HtmlToPdfException("...");
        }
        return pdf;
    }}
    
@Configuration
@Slf4j
public class PdfRendererBuilderConfig {
    
    @Bean
    public PdfRendererBuilder pdfRendereBuilderBean() throws IOException {
        
        Integer x = 210;
        Integer y = 297;
        
        Path fontDirectory = Paths.get("/fonts");
        
        PdfRendererBuilder pdfRendererBuilder = new PdfRendererBuilder();
        
        pdfRendererBuilder.useDefaultPageSize(x, y, BaseRendererBuilder.PageSizeUnits.MM);
        pdfRendererBuilder.useFastMode();
        
        List<CSSFont> fonts = AutoFont.findFontsInDirectory(fontDirectory);
        fonts.forEach(s->log.info(s.familyCssEscaped()+" loaded ..."));
        AutoFont.toCSSEscapedFontFamily(fonts);
        AutoFont.toBuilder(pdfRendererBuilder, fonts);
        return pdfRendererBuilder;
    }}
```

Comment: Can you paste your Java code?

Comment: Yes of course. This is a spring-boot service, I paste the relevant code: